# Is it better to learn the DOM or jQuery first?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have gotten very familiar with the core functionality of Javascript and now I am aiming at learning DOM manipulation. I have already thought of learning jQeury for this but I don't know if it is good idea to learning it before first getting familiar with the core functionality of the DOM.

Should I first learn the core functionality of the DOM and then learn jQuery? If so, why? Or should I just go on ahead and learn jQuery?

Comment: The DOM is more general, hence it seems more valuable to understand (long-term)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Learn the DOM. By doing that, you will have a better understanding and appreciation for what libraries like jQuery do for you. This also means you'll be better suited in the long run if you must change tools. The DOM will always be there, and is common ground for understanding the fundamental design choices for any given library that interacts with the DOM.

With all that given, I don't think there is anything wrong with learning the DOM alongside jQuery. Especially if you have a project that requires JQuery and needs to get done relatively soon. I think the important thing is that you learn how the DOM works in order to keep yourself decoupled from any particular library.

Comment: There's plenty wrong with "learning the DOM alongside jQuery". The two are mutually exclusive. You either consult the magic `$` or learn why hand code is better. Try following the source code in jQuery. It's a pile of spaghetti.

Comment: @Matt: I didn't mean to imply that two should be mixed arbitrarily. I meant that someone could, in order to learn, implement a feature using the DOM, and then re-implement it in jQuery. You don't have to look at source code in order to compare how their APIs differ. Especially since both have fairly good documentation.

Comment: You can learn a lot about JavaScript from that spaghetti.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery depends on you knowing the DOM because that is what you are manipulating.
"There's not much point to jQuery without the DOM"

the DOM is just HTML and has no such dependency on jQuery.
"You can do plenty of static site work with just the DOM"

Of course there's edge cases and exceptions but for general learning purposes I would go by the above.

Comment: "DOM is just HTML" is a strange statement, "HTML is a serialized format of the DOM" would be a better statement

Comment: @Michael, who are you quoting? I agree with the first one. The second one is inaccurate. Perhaps you could put some more thought into it then I might vote for this.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

- Do you want to support IE6-8 ?
- Do you have time/desire to learn browser quirks?

If you don't have the time/desire to learn how to fix IE6-8 by hand then using jQuery is not a bad option, note that jQuery is a mediocre solution for cross browser compliant code but it's a quick and dirty solution.

If you don't care about oldIE and have the time to learn the DOM then start reading about [the DOM](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html)

In an ideal situation [you don't need jQuery](https://gist.github.com/1613169), your better off using the real DOM API and using polyfills for browser compliance.

Knowing and using the real DOM API increases readability/maintainability because all web developers know the DOM and only some know library X. It also significantly increases performance because abstractions like jQuery are an order of magnitude slower.

Comment: If one lacks the time/desire to learn about IE 6-8, then I'd seriously question their acumen as a "web developer". Shouldn't a driver know how to drive in adverse conditions?

Comment: @MattMcDonald your analogy sucks. Try "Shouldn't a driver know how to drive cars from the 40s" and the answer is "if you like antique cars, go for it". If you like legacy browsers, go for it

Comment: JQuery improves development even if there are no browser bugs.

Comment: @Lavinski You mean jQuery trolls all over your development with it's heavy performance penalty and horribly inconsistent and messy API?

Comment: "It also significantly increases performance because abstractions like jQuery are an order of magnitude slower." An *order of magnitude* slower, huh? Really? You have profiler tests to back that up?

Comment: @Raynos Only if you don't know how to use it properly, and Sizzle is well worth the slight performance penalty.

Comment: @Raynos: Interesting analogy, but I suggest that knowing how to drive when there are cars from the 40s on the road with you might be slightly closer to reality.  (Neither analogy is perfect, of course; browsers are not cars, and the web is not a road.)

Comment: @user16764 on average when you look at performance differences its an order of magnitude. [This benchmark](http://jsperf.com/select-vs-natives-vs-jquery) says jQuery is two orders of magnitude slower (which is an outlier). It's personal experience of seeing hundreds of benchmark that's its roughly an order of magnitude slower.

Comment: @Lavinski Sizzle isn't worth shit. The code is mediocre and it has a bunch of retarded non-standard extensions to the selector API that are of no value. Sizzle actively encourages bad practices and thus should be avoided.

Comment: I can imagine why one might shy away from a string-based DSL like sizzle but come on, the default DOM API is an exercise in pain that I would not wish on my worst enemy.

Comment: @missingno :\ what part of QS and QSA are painful? What part of gEBI, gEBTN, gEBCN are painful? Your spreading FUD. And if your objection is verbosity then solve it with [some simple sugar](https://gist.github.com/1455456) rather then solving it with 20kb of useless bloat

Comment: @missingno A simple API with minimal methods to add/modify/delete nodes in a tree (your document is a tree after all) is hardly an exercise in pain. I would use words like simple, elegant instead.